# Use Regex to filter Columns (by name) of a PySpark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe with 3k-4k columns and I'd like to drop columns where the name meets certain variable criteria ex. Where ColumnName Like '*foo*'.

Answer (score 8):

To get a column names you use `df.columns` and `drop()` supports dropping many columns in one call. The below code uses these two and does what you need:

```
condition = lambda col: 'foo' in col
new_df = df.drop(*filter(condition, df.columns))
```

Comment: This absolutely solved my issue however I don't understand the syntax. *filter I interpreted as any column containing '*foo' however that's not the case. foo seems to be treated as a substring i.e. *foo* . Can you point to documentation that details this method? Thanks for the awesome help.

Comment: `filter` is builtin python method, than filters any iterable collection. You can find documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: you should not assign the lambda, just use: `new_df = df.drop(*filter(lambda col: 'foo' in col, df.columns))`